# Put pin on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, maps

I need to redirect user to Google Maps page and put some pin on defined location.
The problem is that you could easily center map on some point with simple request:

> http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ll=49.901711,32.508545&spn=5.959342,16.907959&z=7

But how to set a pin with such request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with My Maps.

> 1. Create or open a map.
> 2. Click Edit to enter editing mode.
> 3. Click the blue marker. Your cursor changes into a placemark icon with an
>      "X" crosshairs. The crosshairs
>      indicate where the placemark will
>      fall.
> 4. Move the cursor to the appropriate location. If you want to dismiss this
>      placemark, press the Escape key.
> 5. Click your mouse button to place your placemark. It should bounce into
>      place.
> 6. Add a title and description.
> 7. You can also change the icon for your placemark by clicking the icon in
>      the top right corner of the info
>      window. You can also add your own
>      icon.
> 8. Click OK to save your placemark.

http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=21670&topic=21676&answer=144363#placemark

Comment: This no longer works with the "new and improved" Google Maps, because they've removed all editing functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Cerin  That's good to know.  Appreciate you letting others know that it no longer works.  That said, whoever downvoted this (around the same time as the comment), that was not very nice.  This anwser was correct THREE YEARS AGO when it was posted!  Cmon man!

Comment: You don't need to be passive aggressive about it. Yes, I downvoted this answer because it's now wrong, and anyone attempting to follow these instructions will be wasting their time, just as I did. It's nothing personal, that's just how SO works. Answers become more relevant and less relevant over time. I doubt you would have complained if I had upvoted the answer three years later...

Comment: @Cerin  Not being passive aggressive.  I wasn't going to accuse you of doing something that I wasn't sure you did.  Might not have been you. I appreciate that you let others know that it doesn't now work.  Comments are perfect for that.  But a downvote does nothing.  No one can tell unless the answer is downvoted into the negative. Why penalize the person who provided a good answer just because the tech has changed. I bet there are thousands of answers on SO in similar state. Anyway, I don't care about the rep. I only mention this because I think the mentality is wrong.  Since this answer..

Comment: ...no longer is appropriate given the change in code, I will delete it in a day or two.  (Give you and others a chance to read these comments.)  Thanks for pointing this out again.

Comment: Turns out you can't delete an accepted answer!  So there you go.  See all the comments above. ;-)

Comment: It is possible with the new My Maps too. I made an example: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zAf65De-EVbs.kDzHyQriFSjQ It has a pin on the tip of Eiffel tower (when viewed in the satellite view, until they use different images...)